# Get number of rows copied in ADF, can't see rowsCopied

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity to copy a csv file from one container in the data lake to another container in the data lake. Source and sink datasets are binary format type with identical settings. I can't see rowsCopied in the output.

I want to get number of records copied to the sink to log this into an audit table.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In case of file movements especially Binary formats, I am not sure you would get the rows copied data via Copy activity logs.
You might have to use a lookup activity and iteration activity to get the row count explicitly or dataflows to get the count.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/35029/how-to-get-row-counts-from-files-stored-in-azure-s

Comment: Hi ,@Nandan, how do i do it in the ADF data flow

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK, for binary files are the number of rows copied are not showed in Copy activity output and it is also not supported in DataFlow**

As your concern is to log number of copied rows into an audit table you need to use storage event trigger which will trigger the pipeline which get the number of copied rows from just coped CSV file.

- Create a pipeline with Pipeline parameters `Folderpath` and `Filename`.
  [image]
- Create a Storage Event Trigger For blob created in particular sink Container.
  [image]
- For this trigger Add trigger run parameter `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName` respectively for `Folderpath` and `Filename`.
  [image]
- Now take Lookup activity to pipeline and add ADLS dataset with Delimited text file format with `Folderpath` and `Filename` parameters.
  -- Dataset for lookup:
  [image]
  -- Source setting for this:
  [image]

**Whenever CSV file is added to particular folder It will trigger this pipeline and you can get the no of rows copied through the lookup output count**

[image]

**you can access it using. `@activity('Lookup1').output.count` in further activities.**